# Can't put data from database to a table with PHP

Tags: php

My problem is that I can't fill my table with the data I got in my database. I wrote a code in PHP to do it but it doesn't work and I don't know how to make it work. Any idea ? Here's my code :
view gestJury :

```
<h3>Liste des jurys :</h3>
<div class="tablebox">
    <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>N°</th>
                <th>Professeur1</th>
                <th>Professeur2</th>
                <th>Salle</th>
                <th>Heure</th>
                <?php if($rang == 0){ ?>
                <th class="action" >Supprimer</th>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <?php while($donnees = $listeJury->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
            $i = $i + 1;
        ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row0">
                <td><?php echo $donnees['idJury'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $donnees['idProf'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $donnees['idProf2'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $donnees['Salle'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $donnees['horaireJury'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

index.php :

```
function listJuryGlobal(){
    $jury = new Professeur();
    $listeJury = $jury->getJuryGlobal();
    require('view/gestJury.php');
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting? Is your pdo connection working?

Comment: Maybe it is because you missed `;` in `<td><?php echo $donnees['key'] ?></td>` lines ?

Comment: In your `gestJury.php`, do a `print_r()` on `$donnees`: `print_r($donnees);`. What does that show?

Comment: Wheres the query? What database are you using? How is `listJuryGlobal()` relevant to the question?

Comment: Actually I got no error, I just got no display of the table. My connection with pdo is working because it works few lines down in the code. I put the ';' at the end of the lines but it didn't work

Comment: I added the  "print_r($donnees);" but that shows nothing.

Comment: My query is in the function getJuryGlobal : `public function getJuryGlobal() {
     include('coBDD.php');
     try{
      var_dump($db);
      $query = $db->prepare('SELECT idJury, Salle, horaireJury, idProf, idProf2
      FROM JURY
      ORDER BY idJury');
      $query->execute();
      $db = null;
      return $query;
     }
     catch (Exception $e){
      die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
     }
    }`

Comment: Can you try without setting $db to null?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work